# How to change logo's link URL?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, jhtml

I recently bought a new domain and transfered my old site's files to it. It's all nice, but the logo still points to the old site. How can I adjust it? Here's my new site home page and the logo is in the upper left corner (blue colored with a book image in it)

https://tutoring.solutions

Answer (score 1):

That sort of thing is completely in the control of the template designer; Joomla doesn't care how that's set.

Not being familiar what template you're using, it's hard for me to tell precisely how it's done. From the site's markup, it looks like it's in a module (would probably be a custom HTML module). I'd look for one of those called something like "logo" first. It might also be in a configuration parameter for the template itself (Extensions->Templates then click on the template).

Those are the two most typical ways of handling it. Unfortunately, it might be hardcoded in the template's index.php file as well, or done in multiple other manners as well.

If the template was a purchased one from one of the template houses, maybe if you add which one it to your question, someone might come up with a better answer.

Addendum:
To see if it's coded in the template's index.php file you need to ook in the template's index.php file. One way is to go to Extensions->Templates->Templates, then click on the template name. There will be a list of files on the left. Click "index.php" there. DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING IN THAT FILE! Look for the lines in that file around something like this:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo" />
```

Again, don't make any changes but copy out the few lines above and below that, and that might give us a better chance of figuring this out. Or not (template sellers write notoriously hard to read code).

Comment: this one: https://demo.joomlaplates.com/jp_x2/

Comment: The logo image is in Joomla Custom HTML module in "logo" position. But there's no way to change a URL there. There's just this code there: <p><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="193" height="40" /></p>

Comment: I think it's in this file in templates/jp-x2/layouts/template.php and this line of code <a id="logo" href="<?php echo $this['config']->get('site_url'); ?>"><?php echo $this['modules']->render('logo'); ?></a>

Comment: I would agree with Arlen that this is probably within the scope of the template theme customisation. Try going into Extensions / Templates / Styles and click on the style you're using on that page and see what configuration options you've got there.

Comment: In template style the only option I have is to adjust logo's height

Comment: If you go into Extensions / Modules and do a search for a Site module like "logo" does it come up with anything. If so, when you click on it does it give you any config parameters that might help? Another place you could look is in your top level configuration.php and see if there's a param called "site_url" there.

Comment: live site is empty in configuration.php as it should be since like 7-8 years ago. Anyways, tried putting there a new site's URL, didn't change anything. What I have modules wise as I wrote above The logo image is in Joomla Custom HTML module in "logo" position. But there's no way to change a URL there. There's just this code there: <p><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="193" height="40" /></p>

Comment: Of course it'd be just Too Hard to actually supply documentation to their victims, err, users, for how to do elementary things like this along with the template they sell, right? I've edited my answer above to include how to find the spot in the index.php file where this gets output to the browser, maybe that will help give us a clue.

Comment: As a secondary rant, I just loved their "uses latest web techniques" blurb that lists PHP 5.2, a version that reached the end of its life and stopped receiving any sort of updates OVER 9 YEARS AGO!!!!! (5.2 was first released in 2006, and died in 2011.)

Comment: And if that fails you could try searching for the URL string - eg using something like grep in the file system, or Joomla search, or by querying in the database via phpmyadmin - maybe in params fields of tables such as the Joomla modules table.

Comment: Yep. I wrote the method above on the assumption the OP lacked access to the filesystem. I continue to be amazed at how many cases that applies to.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by going to PHPMyAdmin. There I chose my site’s db. Went to SEARCH. Ran a search for “logo” in all tables. Found it in table “modules”. Edited the info there and saved it. That’s it! Before all that, I grepped in Ubuntu terminal window all my site’s folders and didn’t find it there… with this command:

xxx@xxx:~$ sudo grep -Ril “repetit.moscow” /var/www/tutoring.solutions/public_html

Comment: Using phpmyadmin find the value of the "title" field of the record in the modules table that you modified, then go to Extensions / Modules and search for that module using its title (or part of its title). Once you've found it, click on it to edit it. I'd be surprised if there wasn't a configuration option there to define the URL.

Comment: Actually, you're right. Next time it would be much easier and quicker. Thanks for this advice!

Comment: @papakota having visited your website and watched the background video I have decided I would like to learn Russian.